# Normalize textarea element in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, textarea, internet-explorer-11

In all versions of Internet Explorer (including version 11 beta), the element `textarea` is 1px or 2px lower than a textarea with the same width in any other browser. How to solve?

Comment: use CSS Reset to normalize the behavior of all browsers.

Comment: CSS Reset is something along the lines of: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Read http://cssreset.com

Comment: @martincarlin87 but... textarea is not included!

Comment: Have you checked in Developer Tools what the detailed layout is? And by lower, do you mean a lower position, or smaller height?

Comment: normalize.css does not work. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HXeTu/ the textarea in IE is 1px or 2px smaller (width).

Answer (score 0):

To solve the layout issue of IE 11 (and makes the layout appearance of all browsers look 99% alike), it is suggested to use CSS Reset.

Copy and paste the CSS Reset script at http://cssreset.com

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Incorrect. CSS Reset is intended to fix this kind of issue, especially the behavior in non-standard browsers like Internet Explorer family.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at Chrome and IE, they set slightly different default `height` and `margin` properties for an otherwise unstyled `textarea`. To get cross-browser consistency, your best bet is to be explicit about all the box model properties like so (values selected at random but you get the idea):

```
texarea {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replace but... see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HXeTu/1 in IE is 1px or 2px smaller (width).

Comment: @user2857661, your fiddle does not set `height`, which is a key thing in the answer. And the widths are the same – please make clear what you are referring to when mentioning dimensions.

Comment: Looks like Chrome is rounding up widths, padding etc to integer values, but IE is not, and that's where the 1px or 2px difference is coming from.

Comment: I've forked your fiddle to use `box-sizing:border-box` so we can se the textarea width to 100%, that should make it closer: http://jsfiddle.net/NkvMp/1/

Comment: Same problem with border-box, it is only reverse with mozilla firefox! (yes i added -moz-box-sizing: border-box;)

Comment: Now you've lost me - in IE and Chrome my fiddle seems to be fine, textarea stretches to full width of container and padding is correct? What specifically is wrong now?

Comment: I have a perfectly aligned input above the textarea, I've added a few percentage, and when IE is perfectly aligned on Firefox the difference (but there is little) is sees.

Answer (score 0):

Set `height` on the `textarea` element, and set `display: block` on it (to make `height` applicable). Example (you should of course use an external style sheet in real life):

```
<textarea rows=10 style=
"display: block; height: 12em; line-height: 1.2; font-size: 90%; margin: 0">
```

Using a `height` value that equals `1.2em` times the number of rows seems to work OK. It should be enough for fonts that you normally want to use in a `textarea`. The rest is there to deal with differences in browser defaults.

Explananation: If you look at a `textarea` element in browser’s developer tools, you can see that the padding and border values are the same but content height differs. The reason is that `textarea` formatting is browser-specific and the height calculation is based not only on font size but also on browser-dependent rules. Browsers let you override this.

You *could* additionally set these, as they correspond to common browser defaults, but some browsers might deviate a bit (which is normally not relevant, but may matter if you aim at pixel-exactness):

```
textarea { padding: 2px; border-width: 1px; }
```

Comment: In my final example is both the height and the display block, the result is the same...

Comment: @user2857661, if you mean that this solution does not help, please show the actual code you have tried (a self-contained example) and explain exactly where the problem can be seen. Preferably edit your question, addressing the points made in comments.